# Is there any way to use python script in react native app?

Tags: python, android, react-native, mobile

In my case I want to use Vosk in python for offline speech recognition and want to develope complete application on react native for handeling rest of the operation for controlling my phone. And this should be completely offline so don't want to setup saperate python server.

Answer (score 0):

You can check their example of Android integration https://alphacephei.com/vosk/android and if you want to create a wrapper for React Native. Also, they have a wrapper for Native Script and you can check how they use it for android, for example here is a list of dependencies https://github.com/alphacep/nativescript-vosk/blob/master/src/platforms/android/include.gradle

**UPDATE:**

just found that react native vosk wrapper already exists: https://github.com/riderodd/react-native-vosk